# Continuous Background Execution of PHP file in my website

Tags: php, webserver, background-process, remote-access, raw-data

Involved in automation project, I have a PHP file which inserts raw-data in MySQL database. I need the PHP file to run 24x7 even i am offline to collect the real-time raw-data to be stored for future analysis.

How to run the PHP file continuously in background...? Need steps and where to make changes in web-server..?

Comment: How about a cron job? Have you ever heard about it :)

Comment: Ya i heard..which location,to use the command.

Comment: Use cron job as chandresh suggest

Comment: As Suggested use Cron Jobs - you set them up from your server management

Comment: Depends which Server you are using, if Linux use crontab and if Windows use Task Scheduler.

Comment: I am having a .xls file, which is an output of a PLC circuit. I upload the excel file to a remote server every 1 second using filezilla. Then, using a PHP file extracting the excel raw-data and storing in a MySQL database. In future, generate the report from MySQL database. So, I need the PHP file to run continuously with time interval of 1 second. where to add cronjob in filezilla..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron job for your problem this can be used for background process.
use the below link 
http://docs.phplist.com/CronJobExamples.html

Comment: Thanks for replying, i am using filezilla to upload and can any one suggest in which file i need to add the cron job command or code..i see files like .htaccess.

Comment: Please quote the relevant information from your link and then cite it as a source. All the information needed to resolve the question should be in your answer.

Comment: I am having a .xls file, which is an output of a PLC circuit. I upload the excel file to a remote server every 1 second using filezilla. Then, using a PHP file extracting the excel raw-data and storing in a MySQL database. In future, generate the report from MySQL database. So, I need the PHP file to run continuously with time interval of 1 second. where to add cronjob in filezilla..?

Answer (score 0):

forget the web, if you want a process always running you have to use cli-php.
Basically you need a supervisor daemon that execute you php job and keep it alive in case of exit.

I like [S6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/) but there are many: [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), even [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/)